# Why do we use multiple scriplet tags for a for loop instead of one

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am studying `JSP` and the `Servlets` and have question to you guys, because in few videos I saw that the teacher is using scriplets like below, I used an example `array` without any `objects`just to show better what I mean.

```
<%
Student[] students = new Student[]{students};
names.setAttribute("students", students)"
%>
```

But sometimes when he is using a standard `for` instead of `JSTL` `c:forEach` he is writing scriptlets like this one below.

```
<%
  for (String temp : students) { %>
  <tr>
  <td><%=temp.getFirstName()%></td>
  <td><%=temp.getLastname()%></td>
<% } %>
```

What is the difference between single `<% %>` for a `for loop` do we need to use it like above or no?

Comment: You shouldn't waste your time studying scriptlets in 2019. This technique is obsolete since some 15 years or so. And your second example is for sure  wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Either one of these can be used.  The *only* issue with the `c:forEach` method is that you *may* have to install and include the JSTL tag library.  Depending on your environment and skillset this can be a bit of a pain.

The example you show above uses "pure" Java with JSP tags.  Anything between `<%` and `%>` is regular Java code.  This is built into the JSP language.  The `<%=` is a shortcut for using the `out` implicit object that is built into JSP (see [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm) for a list of all variables).  This could also be written as:

```
<%
  for (String temp : students) { %>
  <tr>
  <td><% out.print(temp.getFirstName()) %></td>
  <td><% out.print(temp.getLastname()) %></td>
<% } %>
```

But now a warning.  It's fine to learn this and, depending on what you for a living, you very well may run into JSP code.  I've done consulting for people who, even today, have JSP code all over the place.  But to the point that @GyroGearless makes JSP's are not considered best practice for new projects.  Ultimately they mix business logic with display logic.  In a big project with UI people and Java people it can make it difficult to separate the work.  JSP Tag libraries were created as an attempt to minimize that but it really wasn't the best answer.

New projects today separate out the display logic from the backend logic.  You write the front end leveraging the JavaScript library of the week (i.e. AngularJS, ReactJS, Ember, etc.) and your backend using modern technologies like JAX-RS to create an AJAX front end with a REST/JSON interface to the backend.